# Login not working on IFrame in VB.NET MVC application

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, iframe

I have a vb.net mvc application. Everything on site works fine. However, i am unable to login when i try to login through IFrame.

When i debug it, the login function does return true but it's not logging in.

I am using partial in the log in page.

```
  <div id="rightCol" class="rightCol">
        @If Model.ShowLogonPanel = True Then
            If Model.Broker.Network.Id = 46 Then
                @<strong>@Html.Label("WhitelabelLoginLabel", "Existing customers log in here.", cultureDetail)</strong>
            Else
                @Html.label("BrokerLoginLabel", "Access saved quotes and service your client's policies online", cultureDetail)
            End If
        End If
        <div id="rightCol1" class="rightCol1">
            @If Model.ShowLogonPanel = True Then
                @<div id="rightCol1a" class="rightCol1a" style="color:#@Model.PanelTextColor;background-color:#@Model.PanelBackgroundColor">
                <fieldset>
                    @If Model.Broker.Network.Id = 46 Then
                        @Html.Legend("Existing Customers", cultureDetail)
                    Else
                        @Html.Legend("Broker Login", cultureDetail)
                    End If
                    <div style="margin-top:-10px;width:150px;vertical-align:middle;color:#@Model.PanelTextColor;background-color:#@Model.PanelBackgroundColor">
                        @Using Html.BeginForm()                       
                            @Html.Partial("_SignIn", New GPM.QuickQuote.Domain.SignInViewModel)
                        End Using
                        <div style="color:Red;font-size:1.20em;margin-left:-22px;width:176px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;background-color:#@Model.PanelBackgroundColor">
                            <strong>@Html.ValidationMessage("SignInError")</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>  
                </div>
            End If
        </div>
        <div id="rightCol2" class="rightCol2" >
            @If Model.ShowNeedHelpPanel = True Then
                @<div id="rightCol2a" class="rightCol2a" style="color:#@Model.PanelTextColor;background-color:#@Model.PanelBackgroundColor">
                <fieldset style="width:86%">
                    <legend style="text-align:center">@Html.Raw("WhiteLabels", "NeedHelpTitle", Model.Id, Model.NeedHelpTitle, cultureDetail)</legend>
                    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:-10px;margin-left:-10px; margin-right:-10px;color:#@Model.PanelTextColor;background-color:#@Model.PanelBackgroundColor">
                        <label id="NeedHelp" style="text-align:center;margin-top:-20px">@Html.Raw("WhiteLabels", "NeedHelpText", Model.Id, Model.NeedHelpText, cultureDetail)</label>
                        <a id="NeedHelpEmail" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:-23px; margin-right:-23px" href="mailto:@Html.Raw(Model.NeedHelpEmail)?subject=Online Help">@Html.Raw(Model.NeedHelpEmail)</a>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
            End If
        </div>       
        <div id="rightCol3" class="rightCol3">
            @If Model.ShowBespokePanel = True Then
                @<div id="rightCol3a" class="rightCol3a" style="color:#@Model.PanelTextColor;background-color:#@Model.PanelBackgroundColor">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend style="text-align:center">@Html.Raw("WhiteLabels", "BespokePanelTitle", Model.Id, Model.BespokePanelTitle, cultureDetail)</legend>
                    <div style="margin-top:-10px;color:#@Model.PanelTextColor;background-color:#@Model.PanelBackgroundColor">
                        <label id="BespokePanel" style="margin-top:-20px">@Html.Raw("WhiteLabels", "BespokePanelText", Model.Id, Model.BespokePanelText, cultureDetail)</label>        
                    </div> 
                </fieldset> 
                </div>
            End If
            </div>   
        </div>
```

Code for Sign In:

```
 Public Sub SignIn(ByVal login As ILogin, ByVal whiteLabelId As Integer, ByVal createPersistentCookie As Boolean) Implements IAuthenticationService.SignIn

        SessionService.WhiteLabelId = whiteLabelId

        Dim authenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket("1", login.Id.ToString + "," + login.Email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), createPersistentCookie, login.SeperatedLevelIds(","), "/")
        Dim cookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket))

        If authenticationTicket.IsPersistent Then
            cookie.Expires = authenticationTicket.Expiration
        End If

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)


    End Sub
```

I have a SessionService class that assigns the value to session. On debugging, i realized that it is assigning the values correctly. But when it comes to get the value. It doesn't have the value in it when using Iframe.

```
Public Class SessionService


   Public Shared Property WhiteLabelId() As Integer
       Get
           Return HttpContext.Current.Session("WhiteLabelId")
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As Integer)
           HttpContext.Current.Session("WhiteLabelId") = value
       End Set
   End Property

   Public Shared Property QuestionSetId() As Integer
       Get
           Return HttpContext.Current.Session("QuestionSetId")
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As Integer)
           HttpContext.Current.Session("QuestionSetId") = value
       End Set
   End Property
```

For example, the whiteLabelId in the code above is assigned the correct value. But it doesn't save that in the session in Iframe.

Not sure, if it's the session issue as i explained above. Cookies issue or the certificate issue. I have tried it on Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera.

If there's something i can do with my IFrame to make it work ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="http://example.com/" width="1000" height="1000">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the cookieSameSite= "None" in the session state tag to avoid this issue. I have tried this and working well.

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None"  cookieless="false" timeout="360">
</sessionState>
```

Please check the given below URLs:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4524420/kb4524420

https://forums.asp.net/t/2161961.aspx?Problem+with+Session+in+iFrame+after+recent+windows+update